# Approximation of a manifold at second order

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The approximation of a manifold at first order at one point is the tangent space of the manifold at this point.

Is there exist a notion of approximation at second order of a manifold at one point. We can assume that the manifold has a Riemannian structure if necessary.

Comment: This might not be what you're looking for, but the fact you mention the metric makes me think of the curvature; which is essentially the second order term in the Taylor expansion of the metric.

Comment: there's the notion of Riemann normal coordinates which allows you to pick a coordinate system around any point such that the metric at that point is the Euclidean metric.  As you depart from the base point, you start picking up errors with the second order correction being related to the curvature tensor.

Comment: Every Riemannian curve or product of curves is flat, which compels us to view a circle as a line to _second_ (and higher!) order if we work intrinsically. That seems contrary to geometric intuition and intent. <> Perhaps you're trying to get at some _extrinsic_ geometric concept, related to an isometric immersion of a Riemannian manifold in a higher-dimensional space...?

Comment: If necessary, we can assume that the manifold is embedded in $\mathbb R^n$. The approximation of second order can be extrinsec but no problem for me.

Comment: Extrinsic approximation is truly different from an intrinsic one. You should edit your question to make it clear what are you actually interested in. It would be also helpful if you indicated your level of familiarity with differential/Riemannian geometry.

Comment: There are notions of higher-order tangent bundles. For example, see William Pohl's "Differential Geometry of Higher Order," Topology 1, 169-211.